# How to use MaterializeCSS in Angular 2

Tags: angular, materialize

I really want to use [materializecss](http://materializecss.com) in **Angular2**.

I followed the steps from

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize.

I'm still studying **Angular2** and using **angular-cli**. But I don't know where to add the plugin bec.

I don't know where webpack is. And I tried to follow this steps too 
https://medium.com/@ladyleet/using-materializecss-with-your-angular-2-angular-cli-app-2eb64b05a1d2#.cpgjvvo7m

but I don't know where `angular-cli-build.js` is?

oh, btw I am using **angular-cli**. I hope there's someone who can help me.

I really like **materializecss**. I'm always using it when I'm using AngularJS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Answer from this repo : https://github.com/stanleyeosakul/angular-travelville

### Setup Materialize CSS

1. Run `yarn add materialize-css@next` ( or `npm i materialize-css@next`)
2. Add Materialize CSS into `.angular-cli.json` ( or `angular.json`)

   `json
       // .angular-cli.json
       {
         "apps": [
           {
             ...
             "styles": [
               "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css",
               "styles.css"
             ],
             "scripts": [
               "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
             ],
             ...
           }
         ]
       }`
3. Declare the `M` variable in `./src/typings.d.ts` (or create the file yourself)

   `typescript
   declare var M;`
4. Materialize CSS is now integrated into Angular!

Comment: Just a little change: instead of ../node_modules use ./node_modules

Answer (score 4):

You can import materialize css in your main `styles.sass` file like this.

```
// override fonts path to prevent build errors (or use resolve-url loader)
$roboto-font-path: "../node_modules/materialize-css/fonts/roboto/"

// optionally override color variables eg: ...
$primary-color: color("materialize-purple");

@import "~materialize-css/sass/materialize"
```

Answer (score 2):

Even i tried materialize css with angular-cli project,followed the instructions from [MaterializeCss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize), And it's working.
The steps which i followed is:

Install jquery, materialize-css and angular2-materialize

Add jquery and materialize in angular-cli scripts

```
  "scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
   "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
  ]
```

Add materialize.css in angular-cli

```
 "styles": [
 "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"
 ]
```

And finally import MaterializeModule in app.module.ts

```
 import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize';
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
   MaterializeModule
  ]
 })
```

Comment: I would like to ask if all the features of materializecss are working? Thanks btw.

Answer (score 2):

Use this npm package and instruction:
***Installing & configuring angular2-materialize in projects created with the Angular CLI*** 
https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize